# No module named 'sgp4' but Requirement already satisfied: sgp4 in c:\

Tags: python, sgp4

New to coding so appreciate this might be obvious - throwing an error at line 1:

from sgp4.earth_gravity import wgs84

which returns:

"No module named 'sgp4' "

however when I go to install using pip I'm told:

"Requirement already satisfied: sgp4 in c:\ ..."

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

sgp4 is a not a package, so installing via pip will not work.
clone the project,
git clone https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/python-sgp4.git

go the clone path

```
from sgp4.earth_gravity import wgs84
from sgp4.io import twoline2rv
```

if required add path.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/sgp4/library')
import sgp4
```

Comment: This is not accurate. The documentation you provided a link to then links to https://pypi.org/project/sgp4/ which shows "pip install sgp4" right at the top and should work.